# How to control multiple PCs with one pair of mouse and keyboard?

Tags: windows, keyboard, mouse, synergy

I found two softwares: Mouse Without Borders and Synergy. They allow to move my mouse without borders on multiple PCs. I'd like to control all of the PCs at once.

In example: I have 3 PCs with Windows installed. I click on 'My Computer' on 1st PC and 'My Computer' window opens on all PCs. I move my mouse on 1st PC and the mouse moves on each PC in the same way. I type something in Notepad on 1st PC and each PC has the same text on its Notepad. Is there a software that will let me do it?

I've read that you can cut your mouse cable, split each wire in two, put a plug on each end and have two separate plugs and then put them in the USB ports. This is hardware solution and I'm not sure it would really work.

Thank you in advance for your ideas.

Edit: I can only find solutions for some MMORPG games which aren't helpful.

Comment: And why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm a trader using Sterling Trader Pro and I want to make the same exact trades on multiples computers.

Comment: Why not make the trade on one computer with the desired number of shares?

Comment: Because one account has limits. And I can't run more than one account from a PC.

Comment: What kind of limits are you running into? This isn't a very practical thing you are attempting to achieve. Perhaps purchasing a less limited version or finding another piece of software is a good idea.